# Quantified constraints vs. (closed) type families

Tags: haskell, type-families, deriving, derivingvia, quantified-constraints

I am trying to use [this blogpost's approach to higher-kinded data without dangling `Identity` functors for the trival case](https://reasonablypolymorphic.com/blog/higher-kinded-data/) together with quantified-constraint deriving:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuantifiedConstraints, StandaloneDeriving, UndecidableInstances #-}
module HKD2 where

import Control.Monad.Identity

type family HKD f a where
    HKD Identity a = a
    HKD f        a = f a

data Result f = MkResult
    { foo :: HKD f Int
    , bar :: HKD f Bool
    }

deriving instance (forall a. Show a => Show (HKD f a)) => Show (Result f)
```

This results in the infuriatingly self-contradicting error message:

> Could not deduce `Show (HKD f a)`
>     from the context: `forall a. Show a => Show (HKD f a)`

Is there a way to do this without being long-winded about it and doing

```
deriving instance (Show (HKD f Int), Show (HKD f Bool)) => Show (Result f)
```

?

Comment: Ouch. I thought that `(forall a. Show a => Show (HKD f a))` was disallowed when `HKD` is not a constructor, but I was wrong. Note that if we assume that quantified constraint, to resolve e.g. `HKD f b` we can't simply check `Show b`. Indeed if that fails, we can't report failure since it is possible that `HKD f b = HKD f c` holds (because of non-injectivity), and `Show c` is true. So, committing to `a=b` does not lead to a complete resolution method.

Comment: Again, `instance C a => C (HKD f a) where` is rejected by GHC, so I don't understand why the quantified constraint `(forall a. C a => C (HKD f a))` is accepted. How can we provide that constraint later on?

Comment: The answer to this question may be buried in this wholly relevant thread: https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/14860

Comment: My general view has always been that the `HKD` trick is a Bad Idea™ because it makes the easy things easier and the hard things harder.

Comment: The core issue is independent and comes up outside of HKD.

Answer (score 8):

tl;dr, gist: https://gist.github.com/Lysxia/7f955fe5f2024529ba691785a0fe4439

### Boilerplate constraints

First, if the question is about avoiding repetitive code, this is mostly addressed by generics alone, without `QuantifiedConstraints`. The constraint `(Show (HKD f Int), Show (HKD f Bool))` can be computed from the generic representation `Rep (Result f)`. The generic-data package (disclaimer: that I wrote) implements this:

```
data Result f = MkResult (HKD f Int) (HKD f Bool)
  deriving Generic

-- GShow0 and gshowsPrec from Generic.Data
instance GShow0 (Rep (Result f)) => Show (Result f) where
  showsPrec = gshowsPrec
```

or with `DerivingVia`:

```
-- Generically and GShow0 from Generic.Data
deriving via Generically (Result f) instance GShow0 (Rep (Result f)) => Show (Result f)
```

### Quantified constraints with type families

Nevertheless, the constraint `(Show (HKD f Int), Show (HKD f Bool))` may be less than ideal for various reasons. The `QuantifiedConstraints` extension may seem to provide a more natural constraint `forall x. Show (HKD f x)`:

- it would entail the tuple `(Show (HKD f Int), Show (HKD f Bool))`;
- contrary to that tuple, it does not blow up in size when the record gets big, and does not leak the field types of `Result` as they may be subject to change.

Unfortunately, that constraint is actually not well-formed. The following GHC issue discusses the problem in detail: https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/14840 I don't understand all of the reasons yet, but in brief:

- Quantified constraints won't work directly with type families for the foreseeable future, for reasons both theoretical and practical;
- But there is a workaround for most use cases.

A quantified constraint should be viewed as a sort of "local `instance`". The general rule then is that type families are not allowed in the head of any instance ("instance head" = the `HEAD` in the following `instance ... => HEAD where`). So `forall a. Show (HKD f a)` (viewed as a "local" `instance Show (HKD f a)`) is illegal.

#### Quantified constraint smuggler

The following solution is credited to Icelandjack (Source: [this comment from the ticket linked earlier](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/14860#note_188736); thanks also to Ryan Scott for relaying it.)

We can define another class that's equivalent to `Show (HKD f a)`:

```
class    Show (HKD f a) => ShowHKD f a
instance Show (HKD f a) => ShowHKD f a
```

Now `forall x. ShowHKD f x` is a legal constraint that morally expresses the intended `forall x. Show (HKD f x)`. But it's not at all obvious how to use it. For example, the following snippet fails to type check (note: we can easily ignore the ambiguity issues):

```
showHKD :: forall f. (forall x. ShowHKD f x) => HKD f Int -> String
showHKD = show

-- Error:
-- Could not deduce (Show (HKD f Int)) from the context (forall x. ShowHKD f x)
```

This is counterintuitive, because `ShowHKD f x` is equivalent to `Show (HKD f x)` which can of course be instantiated with `Show (HKD f Int)`. So why is that rejected? The constraint solver reasons backwards: the use of `show` first requires a constraint `Show (HKD f Int)`, but the solver is immediately stuck. It sees `forall x. ShowHKD f x` in the context, but there is no clue for the solver to know that it should instantiate `x` to `Int`. You should imagine that at this point, the constraint solver has no idea of any relationship between `Show` and `ShowHKD`. It just wants a `Show` constraint, and there is none in the context.

We can help the constraint solver as follows, by annotating the body of the function with the needed instantiation(s) of `ShowHKD f x`, here `ShowHKD f Int`:

```hs
showHKD :: forall f. (forall x. ShowHKD f x) => HKD f Int -> String
showHKD = show :: ShowHKD f Int => HKD f Int -> String
```

This annotation *provides* the constraint `ShowHKD f Int` to the body `show`, which in turn makes the superclass available `Show (HKD f Int)` so `show` can be immediately satisfied. On the other side, the annotation *requires* the constraint `ShowHKD f Int` from its context, which provides `forall x. ShowHKD f x`. Those constraints *match*, and that leads the constraint solver to instantiate `x` appropriately.

#### Deriving Show with quantified constraints

With this, we can implement `Show` with a quantified constraint, using generics to fill out the body, and with some annotations to instantiate the quantified constraint,
`(ShowHKD f Int, ShowHKD f Bool)`:

```hs
instance (forall a. Show a => ShowHKD f a) => Show (Result f) where
  showsPrec = gshowsPrec :: (ShowHKD f Int, ShowHKD f Bool) => Int -> Result f -> ShowS
```

As before, those constraints can be automated with generics, so the only thing that changes in this implementation from one type to another is the name `Result`:

```hs
instance (forall a. Show a => ShowHKD f a) => Show (Result f) where
  showsPrec = gshowsPrec :: ShowHKDFields f (Rep (Result HKDTag)) => Int -> Result f -> ShowS

-- New definitions: ShowHKDFields and HKDTag; see gist at the end.
```

And with a bit more effort, we can have `DerivingVia` too:

```hs
deriving via GenericallyHKD Result f instance (forall a. Show a => ShowHKD f a) => Show (Result f)

-- New definition: GenericallyHKD; see gist.
```

---

Full gist: https://gist.github.com/Lysxia/7f955fe5f2024529ba691785a0fe4439

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can do such thing, but I could certainly be wrong. In your example you are missing an extra constraint `Show (f a)` in order for it to be complete:

```
deriving instance (forall a. (Show a, Show (f a)) => 
   Show (HKD f a)) => Show (Result f)
```

But that would mean that `Show` instance for `f a` cannot depend on `a`, which can be true for specific `f`, but not in general.

**Edit**

But at the same time it is possible to write something like that without the `TypeFamilies`:

```hs
data Bar f = MkBar (f Int)

deriving instance (forall a . Show a => Show (f a)) => Show (Bar f)
```

So, I am not sure why GHC can't figure it out.

**Edit 2**

Here is an interesting observation, this compiles:

```hs
type family HKD f a where
    -- HKD Identity a = a
    HKD f Int = Int
    HKD f a = f a

data Result f = MkResult
    { foo :: HKD f Int
    , bar :: HKD f Bool
    }

deriving instance (forall a. Show a => Show (f a)) => Show (Result f)
```

and works as expected:

```
λ> show $ MkResult 5 (Just True)
"MkResult {foo = 5, bar = Just True}"
```

So, it looks like matching on `f` somehow messes up the type checker.

Worth noting, that restricting to `Show (HDK f a)` even for the simplified example also gives the same compile time error as in the question:

```hs
deriving instance (forall a. Show a => Show (HKD f a)) => Show (Result f)
```